# Anyone know how to edit a global variable python?

Tags: python

I use **repl.it** for all my coding, and have put a link to the one this question is about just below.
https://repl.it/@harrisoncopp/LoginRegister-Test-messy-code

I'm trying to code a Higher/Lower game, where the user guesses if the next number will be higher than the last.

I've put some of the code below, but it might make more sense if you go to the repl and check.

The score is defined elsewhere upon the user logging it, when it pulls their score from the file - and turns it into a variable.

Then the `gameMenu()` shows how many coins (score) the person has.

If the user guesses correctly in `playGame()`, I want it to +1 to coins.

Then I want the new coins variable to be displayed in `gameMenu()` when the script "transports" them back.

I know this all seems really complicated to explain, it might be easier if you check the repl.

But the error I get when trying to do `int(score+1)` is this:

> `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`

```
# Game section
def playGame():
  clear()
  print("===== Higher or Lower =====")
  global score
  print("Coins = ", score)
  print("\n")
  number1 = random.randint(0, 1000)
  number2 = random.randint(0, 1000)
  print("First Number: ", number1)
  print("\nWill the next number be [H]igher or [L]ower?")
  x = input("> ")
  if x == "H":
    if number1 < number2:
      print("Correct!")
      sleep(1)
      int(score+1)
      gameMenu()
    else:
      sleep(1)
      print("Sorry! You were wrong.")
      gameMenu()
  elif x == "L":
    if number1 > number2:
      print("Correct.")
      sleep(1)
      int(score+1)
      gameMenu()
    else:
      print("Sorry! You were wrong.")
      sleep(1)
      gameMenu()
  else:
    print("Option not recognised, going back to game menu.")
    sleep(1)
    gameMenu()

# Shows user the main game menu.
def gameMenu():
  clear()
  print("===== Higher or Lower =====")
  print("Coins = ", score)
  print("\n")
  print("(1) Play Round")
  print("(2) See Tutorial")
  print("(3) Save score")
  x = input("> ")
  if x == "1":
    playGame()
  elif x == "2":
    tutorial()
  elif x == "3":
    savescore()
```

Comment: `score` is obviously a string, not an integer.

Comment: In any case, `int(score+1)` wouldn't increase `score` by 1 even if it was an integer. For that you would want `score += 1`. But `global` variable are generally bad news, so you'll want to address removing that before going further

Comment: @roganjosh Don't I need them to be global though as I reference to their score in multiple places under different defs ?

Comment: Why can't you just pass `score` as an argument to each function?

Answer (score 0):

> But the error I get when trying to do int(score+1) is this:
>
> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

The error tells me that you're trying to add a `str` to an `int`.  Since `1` is an `int` that means `score` must be a `str`.  You want to turn it into an `int` **before** you try to add 1 to it, not after:

```
int(score) + 1
```

Comment: Still won't increment `score` as it currently is. The modification is just thrown away; they need to assign back to the name

Comment: How do you eat an elephant?  One bite at a time.

Comment: @roganjosh How would I do that?

Comment: @HarrisonCopp `score = int(score) + 1`. That may break things elsewhere, though, if other parts of the code relies on `score` being a string. In which case, you'd need `score = str(int(score) + 1)` but it's a bit silly at that point